# How to create new dataframe by repeating 1 column and sequentially repeating a 2nd column of original dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, repeat, sequential

Im trying to create a new dataframe by repeating values in original-df column 1 and corresponding them to repeating values from original-df column 2.  However, the values should repeat in a different manner for each column.  For example, values from original-df column 1 will repeat as 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3.  Where as values from original-df column 2 should repeat as 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3.

```
#here is original df
df1<-data.frame(x=1:3, y=10:12)

#I've tried the followig:
data.frame(x=df1$x,y=df1[,2])->df2

range<-1:3
data.frame(x=df1$x,y=df1$y[range,2])->df3

#I then tried this:
rep(df1$x,df1$y[l,2])->df4


#output either looks like this:
   x  y
1  1 10
2  2 11
3  3 12

#Or I receive an error message:
Error in df1$y[1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions


#I expect data output to look like this:
  x  y
  1  10
  2  10
  3  10
  1  11
  2  11
  3  11
  1  12
  2  12
  3  12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `expand`

```
library(tidyr)
expand(df1, x, y)
```

---

Or with `expand.grid` from `base R`

```
do.call(expand.grid, df1)
```